# MySQL Cron Script with Load data commands errors only when run by Cron

Tags: mysql, linux, cron

I have having an issue loading data to a MySQL DB using cron to run the script.  When the script is run by cron the load process always fails with error that it can't find the file.  From the command line if I execute the script as root (same user as cron runs it as) it runs just fine.  (only has an issue when run by cron)

I have other scripts that I run that execute SQL queries and they run without issue.  Is there a trick to being able to use cron to run a script that contains load data statements?

Initially I though it might be a permissions issue, but it runs from the command line so I don't think that is the issue.  I did change the permissions on the file being loaded to 777 and it fails with the same error.

line from /etc/crontab:

```
40 9 * * sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri root /home/scripts/loadDWfiles
```

Output from MySQL load data file when run via cron:

```
ERROR 13 (HY000) at line 10: Can't get stat of '/home/load/LOAD.txt' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
--------------
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/load/LOAD.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE do.EVENTS FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ignore 2 lines
--------------

Bye
```

contents of loadDWfile script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -vvv < /home/dbscripts/load  >> /var/log/loadresults`date '+%m-%d-%Y--%H-%M-%S'`.txt 2>&1
```

contents of load file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/load/LOAD.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE dbo.EVENTS FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ignore 2 lines;
show warnings;
```

Comment: does /home/load/LOAD.txt exist?

Comment: Yes, it does.  If I go to the command line and type "/home/scripts/loadDWfiles" the script runs without any issues.